# How to accept any derived class KClass

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

I have this code

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

fun <T: Any> test(arr: Array<KClass<T>>) {
    print(arr)
}

fun main() {
    test<Number>(arrayOf(Int::class, Short::class))
}
```

But this will throw

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Number but Int was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is Short but Int was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is Number but Short was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Short was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is KClass<Short> but KClass<Int> was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is KClass<Int> but KClass<Short> was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is KClass<Short> but KClass<Int> was expected
```

Everytime I run it

[Play](https://pl.kotl.in/-whGXEjQ_?theme=darcula)

Comment: While it does give a warning for unchecked cast it seems to work by calling it like `test(arrayOf(Int::class, Short::class) as Array<KClass<Number>>)`

Comment: `arr: Array<KClass<out T>>`

Comment: @Slaw can you write an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [use-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) and change the parameter type to `Array<KClass<out T>>`.

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

fun <T: Any> test(arr: Array<KClass<out T>>) {
    print(arr)
}

fun main() {
    test<Number>(arrayOf(Int::class, Short::class))
}
```